# Backup Exec b2d NAS

Tags: backup, network-attached-storage, backupexec, drobo

I'd like to backup my servers to a Drobo NAS which shows up in Windows as a network drive.  It doesn't seem possible in Backup Exec 2010 to create a backup to disk folder on a mapped network drive.  I feel like I must be missing something here.

Comment: Which version of backupexec? We do D2D backups to a NAS every day on BE12.5

Comment: 2010.  I think the issue comes up more because the drobo isn't a member of the domain(no option to join). I think I need to configure the backup exec service account to have full access to the drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this recently with my backups.  when you go to add the device use the name\share as the path and it will work. (ie. \DroboName\ShareName).  I also had to change a share setting on the drobo to add everybody to the share since BE can't pass the login information for a secure share.