# Backup Exec backup-to-disk folder creation - Access denied

Tags: backup, samba, cifs, backupexec

I'm having a difficult time creating a backup-to-disk folder in Symantec Backup Exec 12.5 and Backup Exec 2010. The backend storage is a Nexenta/ZFS-based NAS filer sharing the volume via CIFS. I've also seen the issue on other *nix-based NAS devices.

I've attempted mapping the drive, providing the full paths to the folder, etc. I can browse to the share just fine from within Windows, but Backup Exec fails to create the B2D folder with different variants of a `Unable to create new backup folder. Access denied` error.

I've attempted creating service accounts in Backup Exec to handle the authentication, but nothing seems to work. What's the key to making this work?

Update: Here's the event viewer log:

```
An error occurred while processing a B2D command.
 Changer: CreatePath() CreateDirectory1 failed (\\storage1\vol1_backup\).  Error=5
```

Comment: check [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/210181/getting-an-access-denied-error-when-trying-to-create-backup-job-for-backup-exec) out to see if anything there helps?

Comment: It was close, but I think there are some other issues. This shouldn't be so difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by using the Symantec Backup Exec Backup-to-Disk Test Tool found here:
http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH71830

This allowed me to debug the issue and realize that passthrough authentication was being used in the effort to create a B2D folder. In my case, I was logged into the backup server as `DOMAIN\Administrator`. On the Nexenta system, I needed to create an Active Directory ID mapping of `Administrator@DOMAIN.COM == root` (or any other local Nexenta user), then create an ACL for that user for the CIFS share I was presenting to Backup Exec.

Basically, if you're using a NAS device that's not Windows based, you need to allow permissions from Backup Exec; either by leaving the share entirely open or tweaking the ACLs to fit the account that Backup Exec is running as.